# Facebook API ads_posts comments filter

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am currently getting Ads Posts with comments via the following URL:

PAGE ID/ads_posts?fields=comments.limit(300)%7Bcomments.summary(true),parent,message,from,likes,created_time,comment_count,like_count,is_hidden,message_tags%7D,message&include_inline_create=true&limit=10

It returns the correct data, but I want to exclude all postings, which don't have comments.
Is there a filter like &comments=true? I couldn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: Did you get any solution? also, what permissions you are required to have on the PAGE_ID?

Comment: @LauraUzcategui no unfortunately not - i looped through all entries and only respected those having comments in my code. You can find the permissions in the documentations https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ads_posts/

Comment: Thanks. 

I’m trying to fetch comments from my ads on a page post but the endpoint returns an empty response.